# how to create a dictionary from a set of properly formatted tuples in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a simple way to create a dictionary from a list of formatted tuples. e.g. if I do something like:

```
    d={"responseStatus":"SUCCESS","sessionId":"01234","userId":2000004904}
```

This creates a dictionary called d. However, if I want to create a dictionary from a string which contains the same string, I can't do that

```
    res=<some command that returns {"responseStatus":"SUCCESS","sessionId":"01234","userId":2000004904}>
    print res
    # returns {"responseStatus":"SUCCESS","sessionId":"01234","userId":2000004904}
    d=dict(res)
```

This throws an error that says:

```
    ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Do you have a specific example of `<some command that returns ...>`?

Comment: That looks suspiciously like [json](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/json/)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly strongly suspect that you have json on your hands.

```
import json

d = json.loads('{"responseStatus":"SUCCESS","sessionId":"01234","userId":2000004904}')
```

would give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use dict(zip(tuples))

```
>>> u = ("foo", "bar")
>>> v = ("blah", "zoop")
>>> d = dict(zip(u, v))
>>> d
{'foo': 'blah', 'bar': 'zoop'}
```

Note, if you have an odd number of tuples this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you gave is, `res` is

```
# returns {"responseStatus":"SUCCESS","sessionId":"01234","userId":2000004904}
```

So the plan is to grab the string starting at the curly brace to the end and use `json` to decode it:

```
import json

# Discard the text before the curly brace
res = res[res.index('{'):]  

# Turn that text into a dictionary
d = json.loads(res)
```

Answer (score -2):

All you need to do in your particular case is

```
d = eval(res)
```

And please keep security in mind when using eval, especially if you're mixing it with ajax/json.

**UPDATE**

Since others pointed out you might be getting this data over the web and it isn't just a "how to make this work" question, use this:

```
import json
json.loads(res)
```

Comment: If there's a possibility that there's user code being received, eval shouldn't be used for risk of arbitrary code injection.

Comment: There's no reason to jump straight to `eval()`, especially when the safer `ast.literal_eval()` would be better.